# How to change which user:group apache/php uploads files as in Drupal and Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, apache, drupal, permissions

I am trying to figure out how to change how files are uploaded on both my Drupal and Wordpress installs on the same server. The files are being saved with the Apache user and Apache group, but I want them to be saved with the default FTP account and Apache group, this way they will correspond to the recommend settings by both blog systems.

This is how it is uploading now:
-rw-rw---- 1 wwwrun www 94144 Aug 11 10:17 image.jpg

Like it to be:
-rw-rw---- 1 useracct www 94144 Aug 11 10:17 image.jpg

I know the permissions are being set by a php script inside Wordpress based on the parent folder permissions, but not sure where the user:group is being set.

Comment: As reference on my other server, hosted by Media Temple, the plesk installed version of Wordpress uploads files as my FTPaccount:psacln. I am able to delete the files as well as Wordpress (apache). And on the other server I'd like to replicate this setup without having to add my user account to the Apache group.

Answer (score 0):

Use php-fpm + mod_proxy_fcgi to run you PHP content outside of the httpd process under whichever user you like (useracct)

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not sure exactly what that is. And googling looks like might be beyond my abilities. So there is no general server setting for that?